# PHP - cant get value with json_decode

Tags: php, json

The API is:

```
{"status":1,"data":[{"address":"0x5c48aebbbbdcf44f5f181edbb5b20a68210eacfe","balance":6000000000000000000,"nonce":null,"code":"0x","name":null,"storage":null,"firstSeen":null}]}
```

I am trying to get the value from Balance (6000000000000000000). I also need to divide this value with 1000000000000000000 in meantime...

I tried:

```
$obj = json_decode($json,true);
$address = $obj['address'];

$json = file_get_html('https://etherchain.org/api/account/'.$address);
$obj = json_decode($json);
$v = (get_object_vars($obj->data));
$balance = $v['balance'];
$_SESSION['balance'] = $balance;
```

It doesn't work.

The same code works with the API below:

```
{"status":"success","data":{"address":"LU4P8fVNj8xv2dwRc7fdXmpaW2xuCSJvUK","is_unknown":false,"balance":0,"balance_multisig":0,"totalreceived":0.0340576,"nb_txs":11,"first_tx":{"time_utc":"2015-08-30T09:51:05Z","tx":"10f4b55d0bead8d3d84fe27433db20b63368d65bc043c651d59dbe1342d14098","block_nb":"842330","value":0.00704229,"confirmations":251241},"last_tx":{"time_utc":"2016-02-02T16:09:23Z","tx":"c666d3acf6f57fd86a2ccc9537ee022167da408f26193e4abbd7b8148fc518b3","block_nb":"932771","value":-0.01250452,"confirmations":160800},"is_valid":true},"code":200,"message":""}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The data is located in `$obj['data']['address']` perhaps next time do a little bit of debugging first with `var_dump()`

Comment: @Xorifelse should it be 
    `$v = (get_object_vars($obj->data->address));`

    `$balance = $v['balance'];`

i still can't get it to work. sorry a newbie here.

Comment: The url that is constructed: https://etherchain.org/api/account/LU4P8fVNj8xv2dwRc7fdXmpaW2xuCSJvUK, returns the data as empty set: {"status":1,"data":[]}, balance wouldn't be in it and php and will cause php to bark a warning that balance is not part of object (check warning level and php log), unless that url behaves differently if logged in on your machine

Comment: Yeah, I missed the part where its also the first array. Updated it in my answer.

Comment: The exact url is: https://etherchain.org/api/account/0x5c48aebbbbdcf44f5f181edbb5b20a68210eacfe

Comment: oh then it is just  `$v[0]['balance'];`

Comment: @danchik Now you're missing the part where it is also in the data array..

Comment: @JimJ Just look at my answer, works.

Comment: @Xorifelse he edited the code to already parse the data into $v: `$v = (get_object_vars($obj->data));`

Comment: @danchik 
 
My original code works with the 2nd API but not with the 1st one. and the two APIs are almost the same. 

There gotta be some small edit which needs to be done (and which I am not seeing)..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because you're missing that the address is located in the **first** `data` array in the JSON string and in the second JSON string, no array exists inside the `data` array.

```
$obj = json_decode($json,true);
$address = $obj['data'][0]['address'];
$json = file_get_contents('https://etherchain.org/api/account/'.$address);
$obj = json_decode($json);
echo $obj->data[0]->balance;
```

Comment: I tried:  

`$obj = json_decode($json,true);`  


  `$address = $obj['data'][0]['address'];`  

`$json = file_get_html('https://etherchain.org/api/account/'.$address);  
$obj = json_decode($json);  
$v = (get_object_vars($obj->data[0]->balance));`  

`$balance = $v['balance'];  

$_SESSION['balance'] = $balance;`  

And still nothing.

Comment: I really don't understand what you're trying to do with `get_object_vars()`, why not convert it to an array directly? Anyways, updated the code.

Comment: @JimJ The second JSON string `"data":{` does not contain an array. The first JSON string does: `"data":[{"ad` hence the extra required `[0]`